# JSON.parse parsing a string into string

Tags: javascript, html

I have confusion over the functionality of JSON.parse.

I am writing code :

```
dynamicMsgObj = '"rest, no disc"';
var jsonObj = {};
var isJsonString = function isJsonString(str) {
    try {
        jsonObj = JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}(dynamicMsgObj);
console.log(isJsonString);// returns true
console.log(typeof jsonObj);//returns string
```

How is this happening??
In this way I can't determine if I am receiving string or object, which is my main objective.
Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `JSON.parse` is able to successfully parse that input, it will parse it as a string and a string is what the return result will be.

[Check out the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and look at the examples. This one specifically:

```
JSON.parse('"foo"'); // "foo"
```

And in regards to achieving your objective, you have done that already:

```
if(isJsonString && typeof jsonObj == 'string')
    // is string
else
    // is something else
```

Comment: Is JS typecasting object into string after parsing? But why " 'foo' " doesn't work this way? How is " 'foo' " a simple string but ' "foo" ' is a json string?

Comment: The difference is that `"foo"` is valid JSON, whereas `'foo'` is not. Unlike javascript, JSON does not allow `"` and `'` to be interchangeable. What may be your confusion, and that of many, is that JSON is just a method of representing (or serializing) a javascript data object as a string. And strings are just javascript data objects like any other

Comment: Thanks musefan. I didn't know the JSON method's behaviour.

Comment: No problem, I hope you are able to implement a solution with your new understanding ;)